# Is there a way to make my media files unsearchable?

Tags: uploads, media

I upload a lot of contracts, T&Cs, pdfs and audio file to my wordpress blog. I would like all of this content to be hidden from standard search engines. Is this possible?

Comment: This might be better asked at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ for initial research, since it deal more with general site management than specifics of WordPress.

Comment: the plugin to do that is still not written :( but you might be able to use easy digital downloads for putting a "wall" in front of sensitive content. Less then optimal in many ways, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hide it from standard search engines (stop indexing) then one way I know is to use [YOAST SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin. Once you install and activate the plugin, go to the Edit Media page which you do not want to appear in search engine results, and update **Meta Robots Index** to `noindex` and **Meta Robots Follow** to `nofollow`. Please check screenshot below:

[image]

Unfortunately, I do not know (rather there is no way) to bulk edit multiple media files for this.

Comment: images do not have meta..... what that thing is, is probably for the attachment page. I assume you can go that route with the robot.txt file, but it will be hard to do if you have mix of file you want and don't want to be indexed